# c++ explicit template instantiation storage class allowed but ignored

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, storage-class-specifier

I noticed that a storage class specifier can be placed in a template instantiation and it does not create a compiler error. I know storage class can be used in the template design, and cannot be used in a specialization, but was wondering why it is not rejected by the compiler in the instantiation. I tried different combiniations and it seemed to have no effect on linking. Am I missing something please?

```
  template <typename T>
  T my_func ( T arg1 )
  {
    return 1 ;
  } ;

  template
  static  // gcc allows this line without error/warning but has no effect?
  int my_func ( int arg1 ) ;
```

Edit: Note I'm placing the template instantion in a different .cpp from where it is being used (to test liniking), although it is not clear in the snippet.

Comment: I believe that static is not specifying storage class, but rather it influences linkage. Same keyword, different concept.

Comment: I agree about it normally affecting linking, I mention it as storage class because that is the error I get when template specialising "error: explicit template specialization cannot have a storage class". For functions, static would normally prevent the function being visible to the other unit, but seems to have no affect in template instantiation example (should gcc reject it?)

Comment: You're not specialising: you should write `template<> static int myfunc<int>(int)` if you want to do that.

Comment: I know I'm not specialising, I'm instantiating (missing <>), and gcc allows static to appear in the code. The keyword static is not valid in specialisation and seems to have no affect (does not prevent linking) in instantiation so why does gcc allow it to be used?